# How can I use Python 3 and pandas to extract and put together same row numbers from multiple excel sheets?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

This is for Python. I have an excel file named "translation.xlsx" with 3 sheets labeled with the names of people who have translated 8 lines of the same text from Russian into English. Here you can see the English translation in two of the sheets.

[image: You can see "Fed's translation for each line here]
[image: You can see "Bob's's translation for each line here]

I would like to, using pandas if possible but another library is fine, take out row 1 from each sheet and put them together, so I would have
"Bob translation of row 1 , Fed translation of row 1, Raj row 1" together
then
"Bob translation of row 2 , Fed translation of row 2, Raj row 2" together

e.g.
row 1: French man sued Uber for breaking up his marriage (Fed) / French person sues Uber for ruining his marriage (Bob) /  Frenchman sues Uber for ruining his marriage (Raj)

The output format is NOT important. It can be in lists, a dataframe, excel, dictionary etc. As long as I can take a picture of each person's translation for each line next to each other. Labels with the people's names and row numbers are also not important, if it is possible to include, ok, but if not, no problem.

There's no code here as I couldn't come close despite a long time trying

Answer (score 0):

Use [`read_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) with `sheet_name=None` for all sheetnames to dictionary of DataFrames:

```
dfs = pd.read_excel('a.xlsx', sheet_name=None, header=None)
print (dfs)
OrderedDict([('Bob',    0
0  a
1  b
2  c), ('Fed',     0
0  a1
1  b1
2  c1), ('Raj',     0
0  a1
1  b2
2  c2)])
```

Then join together by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)
print (df)
  Bob Fed Raj
    0   0   0
0   a  a1  a1
1   b  b1  b2
2   c  c1  c2
```

And last join rows together by `join` and convert to one column `DataFrame`:

```
df1 = df.apply(' / '.join, axis=1).to_frame('out')
print (df1)
           out
0  a / a1 / a1
1  b / b1 / b2
2  c / c1 / c2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df_Bob = pd.read_excel('translation.xlsx', sheet_name = 'Bob')

df_Fed = pd.read_excel('translation.xlsx', sheet_name = 'Fed')

df_Raj = pd.read_excel('translation.xlsx', sheet_name = 'Raj')

df_concat = pd.concat([df_Bob, df_Fed, df_Raj] , axis = 1)

df= df_concat.apply(' / '.join, axis=1).to_frame('ColumnName')

prinf(df)
```